# Using vue.js props value in mounted Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I am using props to pass a value from one vue.js component to another. I am using this props value within my "mounted()" function. The alert I have set below is properly displaying the populated value from the "this.Id" variable received from props. However, the same variable is undefined when used afterwards in the axios post. How is this possible?

```
 mounted () {
 this.$nextTick(function () {
   alert(this.Id)
   axios.post('/api/title', this.Id)
     .then((response) => {
     ...
     })
  })
 }
```

Thank you. J

Comment: Why are you using `this.$nextTick`? This doesn't look like a place you would use it.

Comment: The callback to `$nextTick` should be an arrow function. But I don't see how the behavior you're describing would be possible. Can you share a link to a reproduction?

Answer (score 1):

Might be because of the context. Try this and see if it works:

```
mounted () {
  // arrow function
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    alert(this.Id)
    axios.post('/api/title', this.Id)
     .then((response) => {
       ...
     })
  })

  // or use bind, but I recommend the one above.
  // as it's much cleaner.
  this.$nextTick((function() {
    alert(this.Id)
    axios.post('/api/title', this.Id)
     .then((response) => {
       ...
     })
  }).bind(this))
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Amats I was doing something wrong on the backend.